# How to add a login successful popup message after validation?

Tags: angular, validation, popup, verification

I want to add login success popup. But when I added it the popup is appearing before validation since it is on the submit button click. When the submit button is clicked after validation and user verification only popup should appear. Now for both valid user and invalid user "Login successful" message is getting displayed.

```
<div class="d-lg-flex half">
    <div class="bg order-1 order-md-2 img-fluid" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/banner.png');"
        alt="Responsive image"></div>
    <div class="contents order-2 order-md-1">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="min-height: 0px;">
                <div class="text-center mb-2"><img src="../assets/images/logo.png" class="img-fluid logoimg login_style"
                        alt="Responsive image"></div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h3 class="text-primary" style="text-align: center;font-family: auto;">HRMS</h3>

                        <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="form.valid&&onsubmit()" class="form col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" #email="ngModel"
                                    [(ngModel)]="data.email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required>
                                <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.submitted&&email.errors?.['required']">Email is
                                    required</label>
                                <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.submitted&&email.errors?.['pattern']">Invalid
                                    email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"
                                    #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="data.password"
                                    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}" required>
                                <label class="text-danger"
                                    *ngIf="form.submitted&&password.errors?.['required']">Password is
                                    required</label>
                                <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.submitted&&password.errors?.['pattern']">Minimum
                                    6 characters, one number, uppercase and lowercase letter.</label>

                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex mb-3 align-items-center">
                                <span class="ml-auto"><a href="/forgotpassword" class="forgot-pass">Forgot
                                        Password</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 me-2" (click)="openVerticallyCentered(content)" >
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
        <p>Login successfull!&hellip;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" >
        <p>Invalid user!&hellip;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">OK</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C83vs.png)
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiCallService } from '../api-call.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  data = {
    email: '', password: ''
  }
  public isLoggedIn=false; 
  

  constructor(private route: Router, private apicall: ApiCallService, private modalService: NgbModal) { 
   
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openVerticallyCentered(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true }); 
  }

  onsubmit() {
   
    this.apicall.Login(this.data).subscribe((res)=>{
    // alert(JSON.stringify(res));
    if(res.msg=='1'){
      this.isLoggedIn=true;
      this.route.navigate(['employeedashboard']);
    }else if(res.msg=='2'){
      this.isLoggedIn=false;
      alert("mismatch");
    }else if(res.msg=='3'){
      this.isLoggedIn=false;
      alert("invalid user");
    }else{
      this.isLoggedIn=false;
      alert("invalid user");
    }
    // this.reload();
    })

    // alert(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    // this.openVerticallyCentered(this.data);
  }
  reload() {
    location.reload();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `openVerticallyCentered` method should be called inside the subscription block where the successful login is handled. Currently it's called either from click on submit button (definitely not a good idea), or after the subscription block validation (where you have it commented out atm) which will fire regardless of conditions. Thus, move it inside the `if(res.msg=='1'){` condition - if that's the block that handles the successful login.

Comment: Tried it . still not working.